# Load static svg file in react and add dynamic styling

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load an SVG containing a map of country regions and then dynamically colorize the paths based on other data in the render function.

Is there a way in react to load a static SVG file at build or runtime and modify styles dynamically when rendering based on properties passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-samy-svg . This is how you can load an svg file and change an attribute. (No need to paste the svg code into the jsx)

```
<Samy path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hugozap/react-samy-svg/master/examples/1.svg">
   <Proxy select="#Star" fill="red"/>
</Samy>
```

A Proxy element will select an svg element (using CSS selectors) and forward all its props to the selected element as attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be quite tough if even possible.

There are some approaches that claim to solve similar problem of converting string to react components ([react-jsx-parser](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser), [html-to-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react)), or alternatively you can try converting html -> JSX -> JS (last step using babel) and subsequently requiring resulting js to obtain generated component.

Taking into account complexity of the steps above it might be simpler just to render SVG as html content of some div (using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`) and later modify its styles using JS/jquery directly.

Comment: I created https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-samy-svg to solve this problem and improve svg workflows with react.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing hard about it.

1. Loading SVG file - just use `$.ajax` call for the resource, with `dataType: 'text'`
2. Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to put it anywhere.
3. Changing of colors really depends on the way your `SVG` is structured. Ideally you should be able to change colors just using CSS (e.g. swap classes or generate style dynamically). If everything else fails, SVG is just text so you can do any text processing (color replacement) between steps 1 and 2.